# WePay Meteor can't get the Credit_card_id

Tags: javascript, meteor, wepay

In Meteor Server folder, I have this main.js file.
Inside the main.js file, I added this code,

```
saveCC(data){
    var cc = "";
    ...
    wp.call('/credit_card/create',
        {
            'client_id': some_id,
            'cc_number': data.ccn,
            'cvv': data.cvv,
            'expiration_month': data.em,
            'expiration_year': data.ey,
            'user_name': data.name,
            'email': data.eadd,
            'address': {
                'country': 'US',
                'postal_code': data.postal,
            }
        },
        function(response) {
            if(response.error){
                throw new Meteor.Error("WePay-Form",response.error_description);
            }
            cc = response.credit_card_id;
        }
    );
    return "succesful";
}
```

I am able to get response.credit_card_id. But it is only inside the wp.call.  This wp.call function is inside Meteor.methods. How can I get the credit_card_id? How can I return an error?

To be more specific, the problem is that, when the user call saveCC, it return "successful" message even the wp.call is not yet done. So I dont get the Meteor.error. There is also an error, it is about the Meteor.error, it is allowed only inside Meteor.methods but not in wp.call. also the cc is not updated with the creditcard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when your meteor method runs, this is what it does, very quickly:

1. defines a var called "cc"
2. makes an async call
3. returns

at some point later, your async call returns, but it doesn't matter, because your method has exited a long time ago. does that make sense?

what you need is a mechanism by which your method does not exit until the async call returns. you can use Futures for that, and it looks something like this:

```
let Future = Npm.require('fibers/future');

Meteor.methods({
    'foo': function() {
        let future = new Future();

        wp.call('/credit_card/create',
        {
            'client_id': some_id,
            'cc_number': data.ccn,
            'cvv': data.cvv,
            'expiration_month': data.em,
            'expiration_year': data.ey,
            'user_name': data.name,
            'email': data.eadd,
            'address': {
                'country': 'US',
                'postal_code': data.postal,
            }
        },
        function(response) {
            if(response.error){
                future.throw(new Meteor.Error("WePay-Form",response.error_description));
            }
            cc = response.credit_card_id;
            future.return(cc);
        }
    );

        return future.wait();
    }
});
```

Comment: So I need to install Fiber? in npm?